# How to make second line bold using CSS

Tags: css, styles

I have a div which has some contents. I tried this CSS to make content in next line, but how can make second line bold ?

```css
.description {
  white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
  Head of Department 
  Department: XYZ ABCD 
  ZZZ.xyz@ABCD.com
</div>
```

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do it with css alone as it's all part of the same element.  Why not just wrap the text you want bold in a strong tag?

Comment: this is part of dynamic content which is not in control so checking for solution

Comment: then it's not possible with css, you would need some sort of js solution to split the text on newlines and wrap the second line to give that a style

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that with pure `CSS`. But this task can be done by some `Js` works.

Remove this style:

```
.description {
    white-space: pre-line !important;
}
```

and next add this `CSS` style:

```
.singleLine{
    white-space: pre-line !important;
    display: block;
}
```

and then you can write this `Js` code :

```
var element =  document.getElementsByClassName("description")[0];
var text = element.innerHTML;
var multipleLinesText = text.split(/\r?\n/);
const theBoldLinesIndex = [1];
var spans = "";
multipleLinesText.map((value,index)=>{
    if(theBoldLinesIndex.some(i=>i==index)){
        spans += `<span class="singleLine"><b>${value}</b></span>`;
    }
    else{
        spans += `<span class="singleLine">${value}</span>`;
    }
})
        
element.innerHTML = spans;
```

Consider these two things:

*First, make this `Js` part run after the `Html` elements have been rendered.*

*Second, in `theBoldLinesIndex` insert the lines index you want to be bold, which in your case, is second line (index = 1).*